# Setting Ethernet interface with no address systemd-networkd

Tags: linux, network-interface, systemd-networkd

I am trying to figure out a way to tell systemd-networkd to bring up an interface with no IP address and force an operation state in networkctl.

This is what the output of my `networkctl` command looks like. So far it appears that everything is running.

```
IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo               loopback           carrier     unmanaged
  2 eno1             ether              degraded    configured
  3 eno2             ether              degraded    configured
  4 eno3             ether              no-carrier  configuring
  5 eno4             ether              no-carrier  configuring
  6 ovs-system       ether              off         unmanaged
  7 vmk0             ether              routable    configured
```

The links `eno1` and `eno2` are not actually degraded. They are part of an Open vSwitch bond and systemd-networkd does not manage Open vSwitch from what I read which is fine by me. What I am now trying to accomplish to forcing the Operation state of the ethernet interfaces to something else.

Is there a way to force the operation state in my network configuration? From the reading I was doing [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/networkctl.html) it seems like the best option would to mark them as `enslaved`

I tried adding this to my configuration;

```
[Match]
Name=eno*

[Link]
RequiredForOnline=enslaved
```

It did not appear to make any change to the status. Any idea how I could force this setting or for that matter is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is a few years old and you probably don't need an answer anymore, but I stumbled across this post asking searching for the same thing and would like to contribute my solution to be seen by future poor souls.

I am also using Open vSwitch, all my physical network interfaces are used as vSwitch ports and only need to be brought up. The below applies to all ethernet adapters, if you want specific interfaces just the [Match] as necessary to fit your needs.

```
[Match]
Name=en*

[Network]
DHCP=no
LinkLocalAddressing=no
KeepConfiguration=yes
```

This results in the ports coming up and working in OvS and networkctl displaying:

```
eno1 ether carrier configured
enp2s0 ether carrier configured
```

Test machine is a Fedora 35 Workstation with an I210 and I219-LM Intel NICs and Open vSwitch 2.15.0 and Systemd 249.9

Comment: Believe it or not that question was still something I was wondering just about the other day. Thanks for the information.